# How to get bundle id of iOS app - either using .ipa file or app installed on iPhone

Tags: ios, automated-tests, bundle-identifier

Currently I have `.ipa` file and same app can be installed through test flight. I don’t have the app source code. I tried extracting the files from .ipa file using Archive Utility but there was no plist file. I am not sure how do I get the bundle id for this app- (either from `.ipa` file or by using the installed app and what is the process?) as i want to automate this app test on real device

(Note: `.app` file or source code is not available and the test app is signed with valid developer provisioning profile)

Answer (score 30):

To find out the bundle id of any existing app:

1. Connect your iOS device to your Mac with iOS wire
2. Open the `Console` app on Mac
3. Select your device under the **Devices** heading (top left)
4. Enter the name of your app in the search bar
5. Now launch the app in your iOS device
6. You will see the first log in the console like `SpringBoard     Bootstrapping com.xxxx.xxx.kids with intent foreground-interactive`

[image: Screenshot of the steps]

Comment: easiest method I've seen. Thanks

Comment: Search “Bootstrapping”，Kill all process,  click “Clear” button，“Now” button，launch the App.

Answer (score 19):

If your app is in the App Store.

1) Find the app online (Google for the iTunes link). For this example we use Apple Pages: https://itunes.apple.com/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8.

2) Copy the number after the id in the URL. (Here: 361309726).
3) Open https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=361309726 where you replace the ID with the one you looked up.
4) Search the output for "bundleID". In this example it looks like this (next to a bunch of other data): "bundleId":"com.apple.Pages". So for Apple, the bundle ID is com.apple.Pages.

Comment: You can add "&country=us" as a example if you need it.

Answer (score 18):

- Extract the contents of `.ipa` file using any app,
  this will give you a `Payload` folder.
  There will be only a single file inside the `Payload` Folder
- Right Click on file -> Show Package content.
  This will redirect you to a new finder window with lot of files
- Open `info.plist` file using either `Xcode` or `textEdit` there you can find the bundle id

Cheers

Comment: CFBundleIdentifier is the exact key to be looked

Answer (score 7):

Try this terminal cmd:

`osascript -e 'id of app "{path of .app}"'`

example:

`osascript -e 'id of app "~/Desktop/Fontli.app"'`

Comment: That's short and sweet, what if I want it directly from .ipa instead of .app file, is there a way to get it, I don't want to zip and then open the payload and then get the .app file.

Comment: nice, always looking for a quick command line option. For IPA files you can run a temporary "unzip" and then delete the files, e.g.
`unzip -q *.ipa && mv Payload/*.app Payload/tmp.app && osascript -e 'id of app "./Payload/tmp.app"' && rm -fR Payload`

Answer (score 2):

If your app is in App Store,Then you can download the app from iTunes store. Then open that file in finder. There should be plist file. if you open it,  you you will be able to find the bundle id there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by Changing the extension of .ipa  to .zip and then uncompress .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest methos is to install ios-deploy (https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy)

Then just run in cmd

```
ios-deploy -B
```

You will get list of all bundle ids on your device

Answer (score 1):

For ipa file:

1. Change the **.ipa** file extension to .**zip**. For example, if it's helloworld.ipa, change it to helloworld.zip
2. Double click on the zip file to uncompress it, and it will give you a folder called helloworld.
3. Open uncompressed folder helloworld.
4. Open the **Payload** folder.
5. Right click on the app file, and select **Show Package Contents**
6. Open **info.plist** with a text editor.
7. Look for **CFBundleIdentifier**. Or if you know part of the identifier, search for that string in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the testflight admin you can get the bundle id from the app information on that site. Otherwise you can extract the file using archive utility like you said and right click on the application within and select show package contents, this is where your info.plist will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

If the App is signed with a Proper profile, and you have the access to the developer portal via the Apple ID, you can go to the portal and check out the Bundle ID in the identified --> AppID under Certificate, Identifiers and profiles

Or you can access it via test flight.

Or else, as Mike Mentioned, Right Click on the ipa, click show package contents, Find the info.plist and you will find the Bundle identifier there.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the below steps, and Get the bundle id (identifiers) of any iOS application,**

> Go to application
>
> Right click on app
>
> Show Package contents
>
> Check and Open **info.plist** file.
>
> Search one by one line. and Get bundle identifier